# React Native reusable edit component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to create a reusable component in react native. The idea is to have only one component responsible to edit all the fields that I have.

Main Component

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.FirstName = 'Joe'
  }
...
const { FirstName } = this.state.FirstName;
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() =>
       NavigationService.navigate('EditData', {
           label: 'First Name',
           initialValue: FirstName,
           onSubmit: (FirstName) => this.setState({ FirstName })
       })
    }
>
    <CardItem>
        <Left>
            <FontAwesome5 name="user-edit" />
            <Text>First Name</Text>
        </Left>
        <Right>
            <Row>
                <Text style={styles.valueText}>{FirstName}   </Text>
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
            </Row>
        </Right>
    </CardItem>
</TouchableOpacity>
// Keep doing the same for other fields
```

Then, the edit component should be reusable.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // callback function
    this.onSubmit = props.navigation.getParam('onSubmit');
    // label/value
    this.state = {
      label: props.navigation.getParam('label'),
      value: props.navigation.getParam('initialValue')
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this;
    const { label, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Label>{label}</Label>
            <Input
              value={value}
              onChangeText={val => this.setState({ value: val })}
            />
          </Item>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              onSubmit(value);
              NavigationService.navigate('TenantDetails');
              }
            }
          >
            <Text>OK</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

When back to the main component, the first name value was not changed.

My NavigationService in case it might be the problem:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Thanks

Comment: how about passing set field function from `Main` screen to `Edit` component as the way you pass `fieldName` and `fieldValue`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Could you give me an example please

Comment: yes, you can do that by passing a method from main to edit component and call the method on pressing OK button and update state in main component. or else use redux or other state management library

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a callback to your new component which handles this. The new component would start with a state with the initialValue set. It looks like you might be using `react-navigation` so I would recommend that if you want this component on its own screen you could do

```
this.navigation.navigate('SetValueScreen', {
  initialValue: this.state.email,
  onSubmit: (email) => this.setState({ email })
})
```

and on the SetValueScreen get the initialValue in the constructor and in the render use the callback

```
class SetValueScreen extends React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.onSubmit = props.navigation.getParam('onSubmit');

    this.state = {
      value: props.navigation.getParam('initialValue')
    }
  }

  render(){
    const { onSubmit } = this
    const { value } = this.state

    return (
      ...    
      <Right>
        <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={(value) => setState({ value })} />
      </Right>
      <Button onPress={() => {
        onSubmit(value)
        navigation.goBack()
      }} >
        OK
      </Button>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my screens. It is not updating the value when back to the main page.